# Autocomplete for 2 textboxes from same file

Tags: php, jquery

I have an autocomplete code which is working perfectly fine when quering for one text box, but when trying to autofill for 2 text fields, both using the same URL's the first one returns the value in the second box as shown in the screenshot below :

[image]

The code is as follows :

**index.php**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-box").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "readCountry.php",
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
      }
    });
  });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-box1").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box1").hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-box1").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "readCountry.php",
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box1").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box1").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box1").html(data);
        $("#search-box1").css("background", "#FFF");
      }
    });
  });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-box").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 610px;
}
.frmSearch {
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  background-color: #C8EEFD;
  margin: 2px 0px;
  padding: 40px;
}
#country-list {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
}
#country-list li {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
#country-list li:hover {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
#search-box {
  padding: 10px;
  border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <TITLE>jQuery AJAX Autocomplete - Country Example</TITLE>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Country Name" />
        <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
        <input type="text" id="search-box1" placeholder="Country Name" />
        <div id="suggesstion-box1"></div>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**readCountry.php**

```
           <?php

    if(!empty($_POST["keyword"])) {

    $Name=$_POST["keyword"];
    $username="********";
    $password="********";
    $lc = ldap_connect("********") or
    die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
    ldap_set_option($lc, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_bind($lc,$username,$password);
    $base = "OU=********,DC=********,DC=********";
    $filt = "(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=$Name*))))";
    $sr = @ldap_search($lc, $base, $filt);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($lc, $sr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
   <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $info[$i]["cn"][0] ?>');"><?php echo $info[$i]["cn"][0] ?></li>
    }
    if ($i == 0) {
    echo "No matches found!";
    } }
```

**What I need :**

It should return each searched value in its respective text box.

[image]

Appreciate any help :) Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You have the `selectCountry` function twice in your code, and you actually do not need to repeat the post request. Just use `.on('keyup', ...` and refer  to `this` in your listener.

Comment: Hey David! Thanks for your response. Could you please elaborate more. Not very well versed with all this. Thanks! :)

Comment: Try not to repeat stuff if you don't really have to. Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s79yn88c/) example. Do not pay too much attention to the filter, seems like you already have a working filter, but pay attention to how you can handle the `keyup` event in one listener function for both input fields. Referring to `this` in the listener gives you the current input field. I am sure you will get the idea.

Comment: Yes. Got an idea now. Could you please check the jsfiddle you had linked. It is not working

Comment: What exactly is not working in the fiddle? Works just fine for me.

Comment: The search box is not populating anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87970/discussion-between-soumya-rao-and-daviddomain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had repeated function name, and the file name. Seperated the files and it started working perfectly fine! :)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-box").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "readCountry1.php",
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
        $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
      }
    });
    });
   });

    function selectCountry1(val) {
    $("#search-box1").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box1").hide();
   }

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-box1").keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "readCountry.php",
      data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#search-box1").css("background", "#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#suggesstion-box1").show();
        $("#suggesstion-box1").html(data);
        $("#search-box1").css("background", "#FFF");
      }
    });
    });
    });

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-box").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```